# Best design pattern for API chaining in JAVA

Tags: java, api, design-patterns, method-chaining

I want to invoke series of API calls in Java. The requirement is that some API's response will be used in the subsequent API call's request. I can achieve this using certain loops. But I want to use a design pattern in such a way that the implementation is generic. Any help?

Chain of responsibility doesn't serve my need as I won't be knowing what is my request context in the beginning.

```
String out = null;
Response res = execute(req);
out += res.getOut();
req.setXYZ(res.getXYZ);
Response res = execute(req);
out += res.getOut();
req.setABC(res.getABC);
Response res = execute(req);
out += res.getOut();

System.out.println("Final response::"+out);
```

Comment: What type is `req`? Is it the same object throughout?

Comment: Yes it is the same object, in between the calls sometimes it will be modified by consuming the response of the previous call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the inputs, finally I landed on one solution which meets my need. I used one Singleton for the request execution. For each type of command, there will a set of requests to be executed in one particular order. Each command is having a particular order of requests to be executed which I stored in an array with request's unique ID. Then kept the array in a map against command name.

In a loop, I ran the array and executed, after each iteration I keep setting the response back into the request object and eventually prepared the output response.

```
    private static Map<RequestAction,String[]> actionMap = new HashMap<RequestAction, String[]>();

    static{
    actionMap.put(RequestAction.COMMAND1,new String[]{WebServiceConstants.ONE,WebServiceConstants.TWO,WebServiceConstants.FOUR,WebServiceConstants.THREE});
    actionMap.put(RequestAction.THREE,new String[]{WebServiceConstants.FIVE,WebServiceConstants.ONE,WebServiceConstants.TWO});}


    public Map<String,Object> execute(ServiceParam param) {

    String[] requestChain = getRequestChain(param);

    Map<String,Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();


    for(String reqId : requestChain) {

        prepareForProcessing(param, tempMap,responseMap);

        param.getRequest().setReqId(reqId);

        //processing the request
        tempMap = Service.INSTANCE.process(param);

        //prepare responseMap using tempMap         

        param.setResponse(response);

    }

    return responseMap;
}
```

Comment: This is not chaining as you are doing a redirect with every additional api call; API Chaining uses a FORWARD so as to reuse the token and headers and the original request. See the definition of API Chaining here : http://orubel.github.io/Beapi-API-Framework/advanced.html#section-3

Answer (score 0):

The following come to mind:

1. For function calls that return an object: never return null.
2. For function calls that do not (otherwise) return anything: return `this`.
3. Accept functional interfaces in your API so users can customize behavior
4. For stateful objects that expose API as described above, provide a Builder pattern so users don't end up choosing between constructors
5. All methods of the Builder described must be void, and therefore return `this`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `ResponseStringBuilder` class that takes a `Function<Response,String>` to get the `String` from the `Response`.

```
public ResponseStringBuilder {
    private Request request;
    public StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    public ResponseBuilder(Request req) {
        this.request = req;
    }
    public ResponseStringBuilder fromExtractor(Function<Request, Response> getResponse, Function<Response,String> extract) {
        Response response = getResponse.apply(request);
        resultBuilder.append(extract.apply(response));
        return this;
    }
    public String getResult() {
         return resultBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

That would make your calls

```
ResponseStringBuilder builder = new ResponseStringBuilder(req);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Function<Response,String> extractors = new Function[] {
    Response::getABC, Response::getXYZ 
};
for (Function<Response,String> ext : extractors) {
    builder = builder.fromExtractor(this::execute, ext);
}
System.out.println("final response: " + builder.getResult());
```

Not sure if the array declaration actually compiles, but it should work with minor modification and you get the gist.

Comment: how `new Function<Response,String>[] { .. }` can work?

Comment: @Andrew By removing the generic parameters and adding a warning suppression. Does a minor compiler error invalidate the answer to how a pattern for this could look?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) to implement promises in Java. The problem is, you're trying to pass two different things down the 'pipeline:' the request, which is mutable and (sometimes) changes, and the result, which is accumulated over the course of the calls.

I've gotten around that by creating a class called `Pipe` which has a request, and the accumulator for the results so far. It has getters for both, and it has a few convenience methods to return a new object with the accumulated results or even mutate the request and accumulate in one call. This makes the code of the API chaining a lot cleaner.

The `with*` methods after the fields, constructor, and getters are the ones that handle the accumulation and mutation. The `chain` method puts it all together:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Pipe {
    private Request req;
    private String out;

    public Pipe(Request req, String out) {
        this.req = req;
        this.out = out;
    }

    public Request getReq() {
        return req;
    }

    public String getOut() {
        return out;
    }

    public Pipe with(String data) {
        return new Pipe(req, out + data);
    }

    public Pipe withABC(String abc, String data) {
        req.setABC(abc);
        return new Pipe(req, out + data);
    }

    public Pipe withXYZ(String xyz, String data) {
        req.setXYZ(xyz);
        return new Pipe(req, out + data);
    }

    public static void chain(Request req) throws Exception {
        var promise = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new Pipe(req, ""))
        .thenApply(pipe -> {
            Response res = execute(pipe.getReq());
            return pipe.withABC(res.getABC(), res.getOut());
        })
        .thenApply(pipe -> {
            Response res = execute(pipe.getReq());
            return pipe.withXYZ(res.getXYZ(), res.getOut());
        })
        .thenApply(pipe -> {
            Response res = execute(pipe.getReq());
            return pipe.with(res.getOut());
        });

        var result = promise.get().getOut();

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static Response execute(Request req) {
        return req.getResponse();
    }
}
```

Because it runs asynchronously, it can throw InterruptedException, and it can also throw ExecutionException if something else breaks. I don't know how you want to handle that, so I just declared `chain` to throw.

If you wanted to apply *n* operations in a loop you have to keep reassigning the promise back, as follows:

```
var promise = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new Pipe(req, ""));

for (...) {
    promise = promise.thenApply(pipe -> {
        Response res = execute(pipe.getReq());
        return pipe.with(res.getOut());
    });
}

var result = promise.get().getOut();
```

I've used Java 10 type inference with `var` here, but the types of `promise` and `result` would be `CompletableFuture<Pipe>` and `String`, respectively.

(Note: it might be better to make `Request` immutable and pass a new, altered one down the pipeline rather than mutating it. On the other hand, you could also wrap a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String`, and have the data you're accumulating be mutable, too. Right now it's an odd mix of mutable and immutable, but that matches what your code was doing.)

Comment: writing a pipe class with all the variants will not help me to make it generic. Instead I would be interested to write a wrapper over execute method.

Comment: @anz Well, you know your problem space best. A wrapper over execute is fine, but what will it return? The next request, or the next "out" data? To chain them, you need both.

Comment: I was planning to create an executor which will consume a data structure (probably stack) with request sequence(s). And the wrapper is called recursively which will take request object and response object as arguments. Based on my request preference, wrapper will extract the necessary data from response and set in request then eventually call execute method. And end of the execution, final response from executor will contain complete response.